# How to override the naming of on_failure screenshots?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, nightwatch.js

Unfortunately due to using cucumber and writing out scenarios I end up with incredibly long file names which windows complains about. Is it possible to override the naming for the files?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your framework. If you can locate the code where the failure screenshots are created, I'm pretty sure you should be able to rename them. Does your framework provide any starter cucumber `after` hooks? That'd be the first place I'd look. Otherwise I'd be doing a `find` inside the framework for `screenshot`.

Comment: From https://nightwatchjs.org/api/end.html#taking-screenshots-on-failures-errors it doesn't look like there's a simple way to rename the screenshots. You'd have to locate where the screenshot names are defined in the framework and modify that. Should be pretty trivial, but then you're operating with your own version of the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the Nightwatch framework since you've tagged it in your post.

It looks like screenshot filenames are defined in `nightwatch/lib/api/client-commands/end.js` at line 26 of the latest repo `const prefix = '${this.api.currentTest.module}/${this.api.currentTest.name}';`.

The screenshot path is defined in your `nightwatch.json`:

```
{
  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "on_failure" : true,
        "path" : "./screens"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It appears your have a few options:

1. Modify the code in `end.js` to use a custom naming scheme, and live with a custom framework
2. Shorten your test module names or test names
3. Shorten your screenshot destination path in `nightwatch.json` - unlikely to solve anything since you're saying it's the filenames that are the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should've probably clarified that I was using nightwatch-cucumber. That does seem to solve what I'm looking for. 

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible by using the filename_format option, since:
[#2023 was merged](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/2023)